# wxpython ClientDC on loop

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a requirement to display sampled video frames using wx.ClientDC whenever a button is pressed. The code I wrote detects the button press and goes into a loop, reading the frames but does not display it. I am reading frames using OpenCV. I am unable to identify where I am going wrong.

```
class VideoFrame(gui.wxVideoFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        gui.wxVideoFrame.__init__(self, parent)


        self.webcam = WebcamFeed() #opencv Webcam class to feed frames.
        if not self.webcam.has_webcam():
            print ('Webcam has not been detected.')
            self.Close()

        self.STATE_RUNNING = 1
        self.STATE_CLOSING = 2
        self.state = self.STATE_RUNNING

        self.SetSize(wx.Size(1280, 720)) 

        self.dc = wx.ClientDC(self.panel)

        self.verify.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onVerify) #the button
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)

    def onClose(self, event):
        if not self.state == self.STATE_CLOSING:
            self.state = self.STATE_CLOSING
            self.Destroy()

    def onVerify(self, event):
        #self.verify.Enable(True)
        #i = 0
        while i<= 100:
            frame = self.webcam.get_image()#reads image successfully
            image = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(640, 480, frame) 
            self.dc.Clear()
            self.dc.DrawBitmap(image, 0, 0)
            #i += 1
            #print(i)

    def onEraseBackground(self, event):
        return
```

Comment: You might not see anything because everything you painted by the ClientDC might got overwritten form within the EVT_PAINT handler. Have a look at the DrawImage demo. Painting is done using a MemoryDC and then the content is copied to the frame within the EVT_PAINT handler using dc.Blit.

Comment: Hi Christian, could you provide a link to the demo? Thank you for the suggestions